# How can we fetch the actual video source of a FB video?

Tags: web-scraping, facebook-graph-api

How Facebook video downloaders, Instagram video downloaders works? Are they using meta graph-api to retrieve the video? How they find the actual source of the video? I regisrted for graph api and I couldnt find anything related download videos.
FB video URL sturcture is like below

```
https://web.facebook.com/watch/?ref=search&v=852064115974984&external_log_id=146da703-ae39-4bc0-bb1c-2c6c425f9db9&q=crafting
```

or like below

```
https://www.facebook.com/100009498576488/videos/607019007529508/
```

Or are they just scraping the content behind the seen and getting the video?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a Page's videos by using the [page_id]/videos endpoint.

Here is more information on which fields you can request:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/